# Sort C# ListBox Items

Tags: c#, listbox

I'm using C# Adapter method, I add elements to a list and after that I call that list to fill a listbox, here is my button for do that:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  listCustomers.Items.Clear();
  List < Customer > customers = CustomerList.GetCustomers();
  List < CustomerSaldo > customersSaldo = CustomerListSaldo.GetCustomers();
  int total = 0;
  int totalCustomer = 0;
  foreach(Customer customer in customers)
  total++;

  listCustomers.Items.Clear();

  totalCustomer = total;
  int x = totalCustomer;

  foreach(CustomerSaldo customer2 in customersSaldo) {
    if (x >= 1) {
      listCustomers.Items.Add("Costumer ID # " + x + " is: " + customer2.Saldo);
      x--;

    }
  }

}
```

[image: Result]

This is what I get, it's ok but I want to know if exists a way to do this like this example:

> Costumer #1 Saldo...
>   Costumer #2 Saldo...
>   Costumer #3 Saldo...

If you see my code I have a variable `x`, this variable is the total number of costumers, so I think that my sort has to start with this variable, but I don't know exactly how to do it, what can I do?

Comment: Use OrderBy....

Comment: @viveknuna OrderBy? Sql? I'm not using SQL, only C# Lists

Comment: `OrderBy`, seriously? He is making a decrement and you suggest OrderBy? Wao

Comment: @MiguelFlores `var arr = new int[] { 3, 2, 1, 4 }.OrderBy(x => x).ToArray();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reverse the list and start counting untill you reach the end:

```
//Reverse the list
customersSaldo.Reverse();
//Add new items
for(int i = 0; i < customers.Count; i++) 
    listCustomers.Items.Add(string.Format("Costumer ID # {0} is: {1}", (i+1).ToString(), customersSaldo[i].Saldo);
```

Comment: Works perfect! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can probably reverse (Using the Reverse method) your list "customersSaldo" before adding it, and then use the  variable 'x' in increment order.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0axc2h2(v=vs.110).aspx